# Drag a rect and append to a respective group

Tags: javascript, d3.js, drag-and-drop

I am trying to drag the lime rectangle and append to a respective group that i dropped.

I have multiple groups, because that i can't use the `<g>` reference directly.
I don't know if i need to clone or i can use the same rectangle.

But, i can't know who is the target of the drop, because the rectangle first group always change the size.

So for an example:

```html
<svg id="graph" height="310" width="600" style="border: 1px solid #000;"></svg>

<!-- scripts -->
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

    /* create svg & container */
  var svg = d3.select('svg').attr('focusable', false);
  var container = svg.append('g').attr('id', 'container');
  var use = svg.append('use').attr('xlink:href', '#action');
  
  /* create groups */
  var groupOne = container.append('g').attr('class', 'group').attr('transform', 'matrix(1,0,0,1, 0, 0)');
  var groupTwo = container.append('g').attr('class', 'group').attr('y', 160).attr('transform', 'matrix(1,0,0,1, 0, 160)');
  var groupThree = container.append('g').attr('class', 'group').attr('y', 160).attr('transform', 'matrix(1,0,0,1, 170, 0)');
  
  
  /* create group content  */
  var bgGroupOne = groupOne.append('rect')
    .attr('height', '150')
    .attr('width', '150')
    .attr('fill', 'red');
    
  var txtGroupOne = groupOne.append('text')
    .attr('y', 20)
    .attr('x', 10)
    .attr('font-size', "12")
    .attr('fill', "#FFF")
    .text('Group 1');
    
    var bgGroupTwo = groupTwo.append('rect')
    .attr('height', '150')
    .attr('width', '150')
    .attr('fill', 'blue');
    
 var txtGroupTwo = groupTwo.append('text')
    .attr('y', 20)
    .attr('x', 10)
    .attr('font-size', "12")
    .attr('fill', "#FFF")
    .text('Group 2');
  
  var bgGroupThree = groupThree.append('rect')
    .attr('height', '150')
    .attr('width', '150')
    .attr('fill', 'violet');
    
 var txtGroupThree = groupThree.append('text')
    .attr('y', 20)
    .attr('x', 10)
    .attr('font-size', "12")
    .attr('fill', "#FFF")
    .text('Group 3');
    
  
  var draggableElement = groupOne.append('rect')
    .attr('height', 70)
    .attr('width', 70)
    .attr('x', 40)
    .attr('y', 70)
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('stroke-width', 2)
    .attr('fill', 'lime')
    .attr('cursor', 'move')
    .attr('id', 'action')
    .call(
        d3.drag()
        .on('start', onDragStart)
        .on('drag', onDragged)
        .on('end', onDragEnd)
    );
  
  
  /* drag functions */
  function onDragStart() {
    d3.select(this).classed("active", true);
  }
  
  function onDragged(d) {
    return d3.select(this).attr('x', d3.event.x).attr('y', d3.event.y);
  }

  function onDragEnd() {
    
  }
  
  
</script>
```

Comment: Use `elementFromPoint` in `onDragEnd`

Answer (score 2):

First, move your draggable `rect` out of group 1.  If that group is resizing as the rect moves it'll always be in group 1.  After that, you can do a little detection on the drag event to figure out which group you are over:

```html
<svg id="graph" height="310" width="600" style="border: 1px solid #000;"></svg>

<!-- scripts -->
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

    /* create svg & container */
  var svg = d3.select('svg').attr('focusable', false);
  var container = svg.append('g').attr('id', 'container');
  var use = svg.append('use').attr('xlink:href', '#action');
  
  /* create groups */
  var groupOne = container.append('g').attr('class', 'group').attr('transform', 'matrix(1,0,0,1, 0, 0)');
  var groupTwo = container.append('g').attr('class', 'group').attr('y', 160).attr('transform', 'matrix(1,0,0,1, 0, 160)');
  var groupThree = container.append('g').attr('class', 'group').attr('y', 160).attr('transform', 'matrix(1,0,0,1, 170, 0)');
  
  
  /* create group content  */
  var bgGroupOne = groupOne.append('rect')
    .attr('height', '150')
    .attr('width', '150')
    .attr('fill', 'red');
    
  var txtGroupOne = groupOne.append('text')
    .attr('y', 20)
    .attr('x', 10)
    .attr('font-size', "12")
    .attr('fill', "#FFF")
    .text('Group 1');
    
    var bgGroupTwo = groupTwo.append('rect')
    .attr('height', '150')
    .attr('width', '150')
    .attr('fill', 'blue');
    
 var txtGroupTwo = groupTwo.append('text')
    .attr('y', 20)
    .attr('x', 10)
    .attr('font-size', "12")
    .attr('fill', "#FFF")
    .text('Group 2');
  
  var bgGroupThree = groupThree.append('rect')
    .attr('height', '150')
    .attr('width', '150')
    .attr('fill', 'violet');
    
 var txtGroupThree = groupThree.append('text')
    .attr('y', 20)
    .attr('x', 10)
    .attr('font-size', "12")
    .attr('fill', "#FFF")
    .text('Group 3');
    
  
  var draggableElement = container.append('rect')
    .attr('height', 70)
    .attr('width', 70)
    .attr('x', 40)
    .attr('y', 70)
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('stroke-width', 2)
    .attr('fill', 'lime')
    .attr('cursor', 'move')
    .attr('id', 'action')
    .call(
        d3.drag()
        .on('start', onDragStart)
        .on('drag', onDragged)
        .on('end', onDragEnd)
    );
  
  
  /* drag functions */
  function onDragStart() {
    d3.select(this).classed("active", true);
  }
  
  let inG;
  function onDragged(d) {
    let r1 = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    inG = [groupOne,groupTwo,groupThree].find( (g) => {
      g.select('text').attr('fill','white');
      let r2 = g.node().getBoundingClientRect();
      return contains(r2, r1);
    });
    if (inG){
      inG.select('text').attr('fill','steelblue');
    }
    return d3.select(this).attr('x', d3.event.x).attr('y', d3.event.y);
  }

  function onDragEnd() {
    if (inG){
      console.log('dropped in ' + inG.select('text').text()) ;
    }
  }

function contains(a, b) {
    return !(
        b.left < a.left ||
        b.top < a.top ||
        b.right > a.right ||
        b.bottom > a.bottom
    );
}
  
  
</script>
```

Comment: I need to extract the JSON of this svg element to build again as saved. This is the reason of this semantic svg with groups.Your solution dont respect the semantic of groups with childreen rects.

Comment: @user3251174, I don't understand your requirements.  You need the dragable rect in a group but then want to drag it to other groups and on drop place it into that group?

Comment: Yeah! I need that! I used the `use` because z-index problem. The rect can navigate using visual (drag and drop) and this changes affects in the groups semantic(DOM). After, i will create a JSON export to load by JSON.